# i want preview image at same id but at multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html

i wanna put preview at same divs but in multiple. here is my codes.

this is html ;

```
    <div class="thumbnail">
             <div id="resim_view">
        <img class="image img-thumbnail" src="#"  />
        </div>
  <br />

<span class="upload-button-wrapper">
    <input class="upload-button" id="upload" type="file"/>
  <label class="upload-label" for="upload"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Resim Yükle</label>
</span>
        <div class="thumbnail">
             <div id="resim_view">
        <img class="image img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>icons/resim_yok.jpg"  />
        </div>
  <br />

<span class="upload-button-wrapper">
    <input class="upload-button" id="upload" type="file"/>
  <label class="upload-label" for="upload"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Resim Yükle</label>
</span>

        <div class="thumbnail">
             <div id="resim_view">
        <img class="image img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>icons/resim_yok.jpg"  />
        </div>
  <br />

<span class="upload-button-wrapper">
    <input class="upload-button" id="upload" type="file"/>
  <label class="upload-label" for="upload"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Resim Yükle</label>
</span>
```

this is jquery code:

```
  $('.upload-button').change(function(evt){
var curElement = $(this).parent().parent().find('.image'),
output =  evt.this.parentNode; 
console.log(curElement);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
var div = document.createElement("div");
  //  curElement.attr('src', e.target.result);
    div.innerHTML = "<img class='image img-thumbnail' src='" +  e.target.result + "'" + "/>";

output.insertBefore(div, null);

};

reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

});
```

but when i try in the way, it works only at first div, even i add image it show at first div. is there anyway to preview at per div ??

Comment: An id must be unique, you cannot achivie want you are trying to do with an id, you must use a class

Comment: but i want put it in same id.. im using same id in divs...

Comment: Change `id=` to `class=`. ID's are for a single element.

Comment: i tried but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

An ID ***must*** be *unique* within the document.
That's a part of the HTML spec; it's a part of how it behaves.
Therefore, you must find some other mechanism.